How to create a PowerShell script to change the Active Directory user profile path?
I have created a new user and when trying to login to a machine in the domain, it is saying we can't log you in please sign out. I want to create a script in PowerShell that I can run when a user is logged in, so that I can create a roaming profile for that user.
I tried to use folder redirection, but it is not saving the user settings such as the wall paper. I want to create the roaming profile path after the user logs off. How to achieve this?
